# how can I set 2 range dates with js code in air-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Remaking  code from air-datepicker (with range = true ) 2.2.3 into  v3.3.5 I did not find how can I set 2 range dates with js code.

Clicking on button I need to add sevaral days to first date, like I did under 2.2.3:

```
   const dateRangeInput = $('.date-range');
   dateRangeInput.data('datepicker').selectDate([date1, date2]);
```

But reading docs at
https://air-datepicker.com/docs
I did not find how can I dop this under v3.3.5 ?

After reading the docs it looks like that I need to cretate a new instance of AirDatepicker, when I need to set selectedDates
programmatically on some event(not only when AirDatepicker is inited), like :

```
var dp = new AirDatepicker('.date-range', {
                multipleDates: true,
                range: true,
                multipleDatesSeparator: ' - ',
                selectedDates: [date1, date2]
            })
```

I did not find any other way, the same as when I need to run onSelect method by clicking on the button of the form...
I dislike this way, how can I do it in better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a range programmatically with `selectDate` method.

Live example on CodeSandBox.io: [external link](https://codesandbox.io/s/npm-playground-forked-s5mhkv?file=/src/index.js)

JavaScript code in file index.js:

```js
import AirDatepicker from "air-datepicker";
import "air-datepicker/air-datepicker.css";

const datepicker = new AirDatepicker("#app", {
  range: true
});

document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const minDay = new Date();
  const maxDay = new Date(minDay);
  maxDay.setDate(maxDay.getDate() + 5);
  datepicker.selectDate([minDay, maxDay]);
});
```

Html document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <button type="button" id="button">Select range</button>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

##### References

- [API Air Datepicker](https://air-datepicker.com/methods?scrollTo=selectDate)